# Selenium WebDriver needs to fetch specific element from dynamic div array element

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to fetch the text of `WebElement` that displays in the following format. Here div[3] or div[4] is not in order. I would like to fetch these elements on a page and if it matches with given text, I need to click on it.

```
//*[@id="default_products_page_container"]/div[3]/div[2]/h2/a
//*[@id="default_products_page_container"]/div[5]/div[2]/h2/a
```

Appreciate any idea on this?

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Comment: post the HTML code as well.

Comment: It appears that you are selecting a specific link. So ditch the divs, and just select `a` directly: `//a[link identifier or text]`. Can't say anything more specific, without seeing HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a language but it's as simple as using the locator `By.linkText("Magic Mouse")` or `By.linkText("Apple iPhone 4S 16GB SIM-Free – Black")` and so on.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted and if you found it useful (or any answer for that matter) please upvote it.